# .htaccess redirection with chars manipulation

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Is there an way I can use a regex to redirect (301) URLs int he .htacces in a way that    `domain.com/My_Name.html` will be redirected to `domain.com/my-name` ?
Need to replace all `_` with `-`, lower case the chars and subtract the ".html"

---

EDIT:
I need to replace all `_` chars, no matter how many of them are in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)_(\w+)\.html$ ${tolower:$1}-${tolower:$2}
```

Not yet tested, but I'm pretty sure this will work.

Comment: Thanks! Only problem is that I do not know the number of "_" chars... I need to replace them all, no matter how many of them are there. Sorry for not mentioning before

Comment: @Joel You should be able to combine rules: Try `RewriteRule _ \-` followed by `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+).html$ ${tolower:$1}`. I've escaped the `-` since it has a [special meaning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) as replace character.

Comment: It seems like apache does not recognize "tolower", since it just redirects me with "-" and ignores the strings, but I will work my way around it :) thanks!